# How do you handle autoscaling in Kubernetes for long-running stateful services?

Tags: kubernetes

This seems like it should have a simple answer, but we've been digging into this for a while and haven't found what feels like a reasonable option. Very simply, we're running a long-running stateful service. In this particular case, it's managing a game messaging relay service, but we would like to use this pattern in a few other places. This service obviously doesn't work well with Horizontal Pod Autoscaler since the pods with the state can be torn down at any time. We're aware of the SIGTERM/SIGKILL approach and could look to increase the delay, but that feels like a hack, and may not ultimately work if the game sessions are extremely long-lasting (several hours or more).

Fundamentally it feels like we simply need to override two key decision points:

1. Can this pod accept new connections?
2. Can this pod be scaled down?

We're aware of Agones and it does look very cool, but it also feels like overkill.

Right now it seems like building our own Controller is the only option and from the samples we've seen this is nontrivial. Before we bite this off, I wanted to make sure we're not missing some simpler answer. Kubernetes and stateful services have coexisted for a long time--surely there's a common pattern or best practice for handling this?

Comment: Not really, that's why Agones has been created.

Comment: What limitation am I missing here? Why isn't there more control over how HPA works and how it decides which Pods can be terminated?

Comment: It's no limitation, it's designed for cloud native apps, where every instance is disposable. Search for cattle vs pet. Kubernetes is not really meant to run long running stateful applications. Though there are extensions like Agones to provide that kind of feature.

Comment: Cattle still need to reach a certain level of maturity before you "downscale" them :) These applications aren't "pets" in this vernacular because they can be downscaled, they just have to finish. How do apps like Google Meet work? Do they not use Kubernetes?